# Combine Records in Purescript

Tags: purescript

Given I have the folowing records in purescript:

```
let name = {name: "Jim"}
let age = {age: 37}
```

is it possible to combine those two records some how in a generic way?
Something like:

```
name 'comb' age
```

such that I get the following record:

```
{name: "Jim", age: 37}
```

Somehow it seems to be possible with the Eff rowtype, but I'm curious if it would be possible with 'normal' records. I'm new to purescript and it's record syntax.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**note**: When this answer was accepted, it was true, but now we do have the row constraints it mentions, and a library for manipulating records that includes merges/unions: https://github.com/purescript/purescript-record

---

It's not possible to do this at the moment, as we don't have a way of saying that a row lacks some label or other. It is possible to have an open record type:

```
something :: forall r. { name :: String | r } -> ...
```

But this only allows us to accept a record with `name` and any other labels, it doesn't help us out if we want to combine, extend, or subtract from records as it stands.

The issue with combining arbitrary records is we'd have a type signature like this:

```
comb :: forall r1 r2. { | r1 } -> { | r2 } -> ???
```

We need some way to say the result (`???`) is the union of `r1` and `r2`, but also we'd perhaps want to say that `r1`'s labels do not overlap with `r2`'s.

In the future this may be possible via [row constraints](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/469).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation. But just to clarify the matters a bit: How does it work with the Eff rowtype. As far as I understand the Eff row type is some how "composed" out of different effect types. How does it work there?

Comment: It relies on the types being unified, so in the example above, if we call `something` with `{ name :: String, age :: Int, address :: String }` we end up with `r ~ (age :: Int, address :: String)` in `{ name :: String | r }`. The `Eff` stuff works a similar way, we never actually have something where two different `eff` values are combined from different arguments to produce a new one.

Comment: @gb. I think that it would be good to add a warning line that the situation has changed since then ;-)

Answer (score 12):

EDIT:

It [seems](https://github.com/doolse/purescript-records/issues/1) that currently the official package for handling record manipulations is `purescript-record` - you can find [Builder.purs](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-record/blob/master/src/Record/Builder.purs) there which provides `merge` and `build` functions:

```hs
> import Data.Record.Builder (build, merge)
> name = {name: "Jim"}
> age = {age: 37}
> :t (build (merge age) name)
{ name :: String
, age :: Int
}
```

API NOTE:

This API looks overcomplicated at first glance - especially when you compare it to simple `unionMerge name age` call (`unionMerge` is intoduced at the end of this answer). The reason behind `Builder` existence (and so this API) is performance. I can assure you that this:

```
> build (merge name >>> merge age) {email: "someone@example.com"}
```

creates only one new record. But this:

```
> unionMerge name (unionMerge age {email: "someone@example.com"})
```

creates two records during execution.

What is even more interesting is how `Builder`, `build` and `merge` are implemented - `Builder` is newtype wrapper around a function (and its composition is just a function composition) and `build` is just a function application on copied version of the record:

```
newtype Builder a b = Builder (a -> b)

build (Builder b) r1 = b (copyRecord r1)
```

In `merge` there is `unsafeMerge` performed:

```
merge r2 = Builder \r1 -> unsafeMerge r1 r2
```

So why are we gaining here anything?? Because we can be sure that intermediate results can't escape function scope and that every value is consumed exactly once in builder chain. Therefore we can perform all transformations "in place" in a mutable manner. In other words this `intermediate` value:

```
> intermediate = unionMerge name {email: "someone@example.com"}
> unionMerge age intermediate
```

can't be "extracted" from here:

```
> build (merge name >>> merge age) {email: "someone@example.com"}
```

and it is only consumed once by the next builder, namely `merge age`.

TYPESYSTEM COMMENT:

It seems that Purescript type system can handle this now thanks to the `Union` type class from `Prim`:

```
The Union type class is used to compute the union of two rows 
of types (left-biased, including duplicates).

The third type argument represents the union of the first two.
```

Which has this "magic type" (source: [slide 23](https://speakerdeck.com/paf31/an-overview-of-the-purescript-type-system)):

```hs
Union r1 r2 r3 | r1 r2 -> r3, r1 r3 -> r2
```

---

OLD METHOD (still valid but not preferred):

There is [purescript-records](https://github.com/doolse/purescript-records) package which exposes [`unionMerge`](https://github.com/doolse/purescript-records/blob/master/src/Data/Record.purs#L35) which does exactly what you want (in new psci we don't have to use `let`):

```hs
> import Data.Record (unionMerge)
> name = {name: "Jim"}
> age = {age: 37}
> :t (unionMerge age name)
{ name :: String
, age :: Int
}
```